# conditional grep from a Json file

Tags: shell, unix, grep

i have a query with this Json and grep :-

```
[
{
 "name":"Jon",
 "id":123
},
{
 "name":"Ray",
 "id":1234
},
{
 "name":"Abraham",
 "id":12345
}
]
```

How can one extract name from this json where id matches say 1234 , can be random , using grep or sed?

Comment: You can use `jq` [Link](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `jq` but if you want to use grep try

```
grep -B1 'id.*1234'  < input_file   |  grep name
```

from man page

> ```
>  -B num, --before-context=num
>          Print num lines of leading context before each match.  See also the -A and -C options.
> ```

Comment: Thanks Digvijay,
this will give me both the entries for Ray and Abrahm as it is a contains condition .
by any chance can this be refined to just the Ray 
Also, please suggest the jq command

Answer (score 0):

> please suggest the jq command

I take the liberty to fulfill the request.

```
jq -r '.[]|select(.id==1234).name' file
```

- `.[]` - iterates the array elements
- `select(.id==1234)` - filters element with desired id
- `.name` - extracts name
- The option `-r` causes the name to be written unquoted.